# Selecting attributes as rows from xml datacolumn

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an xml column with simple xml like

```
<Data att1="test1" att123="test123" />
```

I need them in a form like this:

```
IdRow attributeName attributeValue
1     att1          test1
1     att123        test123
```

Tried with both node and query functions but it works with elements but not attributes... can this be done without converting attributes to elements?

EDIT: I can get values of attributes but how can I get also attribute names for each row?

EDIT2: solved this, there is function local-name for this.

```
SELECT T.id, T2.Att.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'), T2.Att.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM  T
CROSS APPLY DataXml.nodes('/Data/@*') as T2(Att) 
where T.id = 354
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @xml as xml
DECLARE @path as varchar(max)
DECLARE @index int, @count int

SET @xml = 
'<Data att1="test1" att123="test123" />'



SELECT @index = 1

SET @count = @xml.query('count(/Data/@*)').value('.','int')

WHILE @index <= @count 
BEGIN
    SELECT  @xml.value('local-name((/Data/@*[sql:variable("@index")])[1])',
            'varchar(max)')
    SET @index = @index + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It occures to be so simple:

```
  SELECT T.id, T2.Att.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'), T2.Att.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM  T
    CROSS APPLY DataXml.nodes('/Data/@*') as T2(Att) 
    where T.id = 354
```